# php mailing function - get /'s in the mail

Tags: php, stripslashes

In my php project I am using php mail function. I have send test's as the content. But in my mail it look test\'s . How can I avoid this special character? I put nl2br function ... I also tried add slashes and stripslashes function. But that special character still appears.

Comment: do u use addslashes function  ?

Answer (score 1):

stripslashes();